# Display multiple records in c#

Tags: c#, list

```
        GloryDays.Add(new Songs("Shout Out to My Ex", 200));
        GloryDays.Add(new Songs("Touch",              161));
        GloryDays.Add(new Songs("Power",              177));
        GloryDays.Add(new Songs("Your Love",          210));
        GloryDays.Add(new Songs("Nobody Like You",    180));
        var result = GloryDays.Sum(S => S.TrackLength);
        trackLengthtextBox.Text = result.ToString();

        List<Songs> GloryDays = new List<Songs>();
```

There is more than one in class called songs because this is the class where name of the track and its length will get stored.

I can view the info in the textbox for once record only and I would like to find  a method which allows me to cycle through each songs list.

```
  public void DisplayAlbum(int thisAlbum, int thisSong )
        {
            if (Albums[thisAlbum] != null)

            {
                albumIDtextBox.Text = Albums[thisAlbum].AlbumID.ToString();
                albumNametextBox.Text = Albums[thisAlbum].AlbumName.ToString();
                releaseDatetextBox.Text = Albums[thisAlbum].ReleaseDate;
                albumLabeltextBox.Text = Albums[thisAlbum].Label.ToString();


                trackListbox.DataSource = Albums[thisAlbum].Songs.ToList();
                trackLengthtextBox.Text = GloryDays.Sum(S =>    S.Tracklength).ToString();

            }
```

Comment: use loop for the same

Comment: In this example, you're adding songs to your list before you've created it. Then once you've added the songs, you replace your list with a blank one. Are you supposed to be doing this?

Comment: Give a example and ur other answer is ticked I dont know why it didnt stay ticked sorry

Comment: @ Brandon Ibbotson  the is is created for each songs and song is class and each album have list of songs and they get saved in song class using trackname and track length. I want to pass through each album with their own song length if it make sense sorry its really complicated project

Comment: its done sajeet

Comment: Use `DataGrid` or `ListView` or `ListBox` to display multiple items.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot display on the same textbox all the song items, inorder to display you need to have different text boxes, anyway you can use for loop and display in a format you want,

sample,

```
foreach (var song in GloryDays) {
 MessageBox.Show("song is " + song.TrackName + "length is" + song.TrackLength);
}
```